# Infinite scrolling using sencha touch

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch

How would you implement infinite scrolling using sencha touch?  In other words, either register a callback that is called when a user scrolls near the bottom of a list to load more data or do something more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.ux.Livegrid is an ExtJS user extension that can help you...

look at this ... http://www.ext-livegrid.com/